# Why would I receive input/output error with testsrc ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to write an integration test which requires actually RTMP streaming to a 3rd party service. [How to generate an RTMP test stream using ffmpeg command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507032/how-to-generate-an-rtmp-test-stream-using-ffmpeg-command) seems like the right answer, however I can't get it to work.

As a baseline, without RTMP, `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4` works.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://mylocation` gives me the error `rtmp://mylocation: Input/output error`

I should note that the URL is valid, otherwise I get an error saying it can't open a connection.

I also tried `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://mylocatiom`. I had read that if you don't supply time, it goes on forever and thought I might need that for an RTMP stream. I got the same error.

Here is full output from last attempt, with added params as suggested by @Gyan below, along with verbose logging.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -f lavfi -i testsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv -c:v libx264 -g 50 rtmp://myhost:1935/identifier
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[Parsed_testsrc_0 @ 0x7fddf34022c0] size:320x240 rate:25/1 duration:-1.000000 sar:1/1
Input #0, lavfi, from 'testsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, 1 reference frame (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[tcp @ 0x7fddf3404880] Starting connection attempt to {theIP} port 1935
[tcp @ 0x7fddf3404880] Successfully connected to {theIP} port 1935
rtmp://myhost:1935/identifier: Input/output error
```

Updating to `debug` added some more data like this before error:

```
[tcp @ 0x7fc4e1601a00] Starting connection attempt to 34.224.30.155 port 1935
[tcp @ 0x7fc4e1601a00] Successfully connected to 34.224.30.155 port 1935
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Handshaking...
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Type answer 3
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Server version 3.0.1.1
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Proto = rtmp, path = /identifier, app = identifier, fname = 
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Window acknowledgement size = 2500000
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Max sent, unacked = 2500000
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] New incoming chunk size = 4096
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Releasing stream...
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] FCPublish stream...
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Creating stream...
[rtmp @ 0x7fc4e1411200] Sending publish command for ''
rtmp://myhost:1935/identifier: Input/output error
```

`Sending publish command for ''` is suspect, but not sure what to do about that.

Comment: The URL may be valid but check that you can stream to it. Try streaming to Youtube instead. But first set codec to H264 `-c:v libx264` and also GOP size `-g 50`.

Comment: Still got same error when doing `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv -c:v libx264 -g 50 rtmp://mylocation`. The RTMP URL is definitely valid - I can use OBS to stream there manually. I will update my question to show the full output from this. Not clear on how to know which args are before or after `testsrc` other than trial and error (going before had errors). The docs on ffmpeg page are a bit hard to follow for a noob.

Comment: Please confirm that it did not work on YouTube as well. IIRC, you need audio too for YouTube to accept it, output as H.264 instead of flv1, and add `-re`: `ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=hd720,format=yuv420p -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v libx264 -g 50 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<stream-key>` I'm not much of a network protocol user, but I wonder if a build using `--enable-librtmp` instead of using the native implementation would behave differently if all else fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't notice - `fname` was blank in the debug output. I was missing the stream name/key. I needed to do `rtmp://myhost:1935/identifier/streamkey`. The logs showed my stream name was empty. I had been copy pasting the URL without the key since I had absentmindendly forgotten about it - my OBS is setup to always have the same key but the URL changes and that was what I was pasting again and again.

Answer (score 1):

rtmp://localhost:1935/app/streamkey is usually the endpoint for rtmp based streaming...  in your examples you only show rtmp://host:1935/app, and depending on what type of service your publishing to, may not work. however, i did test this against a vanilla install of wowza streaming engine to rtmp://wowza:1935/app and in fact it did work, and i was able to view the stream at the same endpoint with ffplay

Comment: This was my answer a day prior.